# Shell Script output formatting

Tags: bash, unix, format

I have output from a shell script like below

```
output1        ..... 1
output2     ..... 2
output3                 ............3
```

I tried to format it with equal spacing inside script but output still not have uniform spacing.

I want to print the output like below.

```
output1         ..... 1
output2         ..... 2
output3         ......3
```

Are there any commnads available to get this  done. I use bash.

here is the code.

```
lnode=abc
printf "server name                     ......... "$lnode""
printf "\nserver uptime and load details :                                                         ......... `uptime`"
printf "\n"
lcpu=`cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep -i process |wc -l`
printf "Total number of CPUs on this server :                                       .........  $lcpu\n"
```

-Thanks.

Comment: The `printf` command does what you need, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but i need the output as i said above . any options i need to pass along with pritnf command with to get proper formatting.

Comment: `printf` format specifiers allow you to specify the width of the field. Why would you need to pass any options?

Comment: Please show your code so we can tell you what you're doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of `printf` is that you specify a format string that specifies column widths, etc:

```
$ cat script.sh
lnode=abc
printf "%-40s %s\n" "server name :"  ".........  $lnode"
printf "%-40s %s\n" "server uptime and load details :"   "......... `uptime`"
lcpu=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep -i process |wc -l)
printf "%-40s %s\n" "Total number of CPUs on this server :"    ".........  $lcpu"
```

The first directive in the format string, `%-40s`, is applied to the first argument that follows the format string.  It tells printf to display that argument in a 40-character-wide column.  If we had used `%40s`, it would be a right-aligned column.  I specified `%-40s` so that it would be left-aligned.

This produces output like:

```
$ bash script.sh
server name :                            .........  abc
server uptime and load details :         .........  18:05:50 up 17 days, 20 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.20, 0.33
Total number of CPUs on this server :    .........  4
```

#### Documentation

Bash's `printf` command is similar to `printf` in other languages, particularly the C version.  Details specific to bash are found in `man bash`.  Detailed information about the available format options is found in `man 3 printf`.  To begin, however, you are probably better served by a tutorial such as [this one](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-printf-syntax-basics-with-examples) or [this one](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) or [this one](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uprintf.htm).